# scan jtextfield for input, write in textfile, scan again for new input until user closes the panel

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jpanel, jtextfield

i'm a newbie and i have a program here that scans two jtextfields for inputs and writes the inputs to two text files. i tried to enter a new input for both jtextfields but apparently it doesn't write the new input to the textfiles. here is my code. can someone please help me?

```
        File outFile = new File("Z://Question.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
        File outFile2 = new File("Z://Answer.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFileStream2 = new FileOutputStream(outFile2);
        PrintWriter outStream2 = new PrintWriter(outFileStream2);

        JTextField question = new JTextField(30);
        JTextField answer = new JTextField(15);

        File inFile = new File("Z://Question.txt");
        FileReader myFileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFileReader);
        File inFile2 = new File("Z://Answer.txt");
        FileReader myFileReader2 = new FileReader(inFile2);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(myFileReader2);

        rate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String ques = question.getText();
        String ans = answer.getText();
        outStream.write(ques);
        outStream.close();
        outStream2.write(ans);
        outStream2.close();
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String[] question2 = s.split(" ");
        System.out.print("Question: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < question2.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(question2[i] + " ");
            x++;
        }                                                               //debug
        String[] QEquivalent = new String[question2.length];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of words in the question: " + x);
        String s2 = sc2.nextLine();
        String[] Answer = s2.split(" ");
        System.out.print("Answer/s: ");
        for (int c = 0; c < Answer.length; c++) {
            System.out.print(Answer[c] + " ");
        } 
        }
        });
```

Comment: could you explain your questino bit furter ,its unclear.

Comment: You should use libraries like Commons IO for writting the files. Its quite a mess at the moment.

Comment: whenever i enter a question and answer, i write them both to their respective text files. those text files are for temporary storage so that i can split the question and answer per word and eventually store them in their respective arrays. i didn't include the rest of the codes because it consists of 500+ lines. the problem is that for the second time that i enter a question and answer in the text fields, i get a an error (Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found). and it points to the line (String s = sc.nextLine();). i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You want a code where user enter question and an answer and click a button and it will to a file ? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

When you construct a `FileOutputStream` by only passing in the file, by default, it does not append. What you need to do to make sure it appends is do `new FileOutputStream(file, true);`

Also, I haven't tested your code but it appears you are closing the streams while only declaring and initializing your streams only once, so next time you try to write it will fail because the streams are closed. Try replacing the `close()` with a `flush()` instead and add a `WindowListener` to your `JFrame`. You may then close your streams on `windowClosing`. From what I can tell, you need to make your streams global declarations.

Comment: i intend to use close since i only use the two textfiles for temporary storage so that i can split the question and answer per word. i still get the error - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found